# mvn not producing all the artifcats

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am going mad with mvn config. `mvn clean deploy` only produces the main jar file. not the javadoc, dources and sign etc files. If i explicitly call `mvn clean jar:jar javadoc:jar source:jar gpg:sign deploy` - it produces javadoc and sources etc. but the main jar is empty.

What is happening!! ?

```
<build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-sources</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                            <phase>deploy</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                            <phase>verify</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>sign</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>suite.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                                <name>suitethreadpoolsize</name>
                                <value>1</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>           
            </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: You don't need to add a phase for maven-jar-plugin. Only define the version of the plugin. All excludes etc. are not neccessary, cause that's the default...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for your input. i updated the pom. still i do not see the javadoc and sources files

Comment: Change the phase for javadoc, source plugin to `package` instead of deploy and try `mvn clean package`

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks. I upvoted one of your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the plugins outside of the `<pluginManagement>` section. This section is used to *manage* your plugins or rather, handle the versions of them.

Activation occurs outside of this section:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
      <!-- Activation occurs here. If you have declared the version of the 
           plugin in the section above, then you can omit the version in
           this section.
      -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-javadocs</id>
            <goals>
               <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>    
</build>
```

`mvn package` should now generate the artifacts you want and if you deploy, they will be picked up automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. I updated question with new pom as per your suggestion. I removed the `pluginmanagement`. still no luck. javadoc and sources are not generated!

Comment: I have updated the snippet to be more compliant with best practices, meaning that the artifacts should be produced during the `package` phase. I did this by removing the executions' bound phase, which defaults to `package`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the input